# Cumulative measure without date hierarchy

Tags: ssas, aggregate, cube, cumulative-sum

I've not much experience with multidimensional cubes, SQL and Tabular modeling are more my thing.

I'm trying to create a calculated measure that's a running total across time periods (months). The trouble is, I'm not using a traditional date dimension because this "Period" dimension has an "Opening balance" category. This is a requirement set by the customer.

The `[Dim Period]` table is pretty simple, it has a key which is starts at 201800 and goes through to 201812. 201800 being the opening period. I've tried to create a simple hierarchy, though there are no attributes lower than the Period.

So far I've come up with this;

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[YTD Total] AS
   Aggregate
        (
        PeriodsToDate
            (
            [Dim Period].[Period Hierarchy].[Period],
            [Dim Period].[Period Hierarchy].CurrentMember
            ),
        [Measures].[Total]
        )
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Total], [Measures].[YTD Total]} ON COLUMNS,
    {[Dim Period].[Period Hierarchy].[Period]} ON ROWS
FROM
    [My Cube]
```

This returns the same value in the [Total] and [YTD Total] column, so I'm obviously doing something wrong.

For reference, here's a measure I created in a Tabular model that does work;

```
YTD Total:=CALCULATE([Total],FILTER(ALL(DimPeriod[Period]),DimPeriod[Period]<=MAX(DimPeriod[Period])))
```

Any pointers would be greatly received.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer;

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[YTD Total] AS
   Aggregate
        (
        PeriodsToDate
            (
            [Dim Period].[Period Hierarchy].[(All)],
            [Dim Period].[Period Hierarchy].CurrentMember
            ),
        [Measures].[Total]
        )
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Total], [Measures].[YTD Total]} ON COLUMNS,
    {[Dim Period].[Period Hierarchy].[Period]} ON ROWS
FROM
    [My Cube]
```